# Passwordless SMS Authentication for Native Mobile App using Keycloak

Tags: authentication, sms, keycloak, mobile-application, password-less

My use case is as following:

- I have an API secured by Keycloak
- I want to build a native mobile app that will consume this API
- I do not want to use username/password to sign up and authenticate mobile app users
- I want to use passwordless SMS authentication

I wonder if this can be done using Keycloak, something similar to what is provided by [auth0 passwordless api](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#passwordless).

This page briefly summarizes what I mean by [Passwordless SMS Authentication](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Passwordless%20SMS%20Authentication).

Comment: IMHO SMS is not very safe auth channel - https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/18/16328172/sms-two-factor-authentication-hack-password-bitcoin

Comment: I agree that every authentication mechanism has its own security level. There is usually a compromise between security and convenience. I think we need to choose the right technique based on the application. In my case this mobile app is not designed to be super secure, but it needs to be very convenient to use. So user experience is more important than the security because the risk is lower. This is not a bank app or anything like that :D

Comment: Sure. You can try to implement it with auth SPI https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi